# List View and a Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

I have a list view and a navigation drawer I want to make an application in which clicking on item on a list view will open a navigation drawer for each item. For example list view are students and in navigation drawers we have tests, achievments and informations different for each student. I have no idea how to do it and I need a clue to start with. 
I will be very greatful for each advice,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open `NavigationDrawer` whenever you need by

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(listView)) {
                 mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(listView);
             } else {
                 mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(listView);
             }
```

**But you shouldn't do it.**

This is not what a `NavigationDrawer` is for. You should opt for, for instance, a `PopupMenu` for it.
Or you can choose from many interactive libraries. Consider [SwipeListView](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview). It will show all the options you want to show when a user swipes the ListView item (student).

Comment: Thank You for detailed answer. Where can I find more interactive libraries ?

Comment: See this App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos

It has all good Android libraries with one click Demos (Without the need of Internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into learning about Fragments and listview adapters.

Google has a detailed tutorial for working with the navigation drawer, http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html.